# Varnish purge on page request

Tags: varnish

I have zero experience with varnish. I want to setup varnish to do something very basic: I have two pages

```
http://mysite.com/
http://mysite.com/additem
```

I want to cache `http://mysite.com/additem` for 10 minutes and `http://mysite.com/` for 1 minute but whenever `http://mysite.com/additem` is visited, I want to to clean the cache for `http://mysite.com/`. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

IIRC there's a cli program (purge) which you could call from http://mysite.com/additem, or use curl to send a purge instruction (as a HTTP verb) e.g.

```
curl -X PURGE http://mysite.com/
```

But this presupposes you've got scripting at http://mysite.com/additem

I imagine it would be possible to call the purge in a VCL handler for http://mysite.com/additem

```
sub vcl_recv {
   if (req.url ~ "^http://mysite.com/additem") {
      purge("req.url == http://mysite.com/");
   }
}
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

Part 1:

This command will clean (purge) a sub-folder (for example)

```
varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6082 "ban req.http.host == mysite.com && req.url ~ ^/fold/.*$"
```

For your domain root, this will work*

```
varnishadm -S /etc/varnish/secret -T localhost:6082 "ban req.http.host == mysite.com && req.url ~ ^/.*$"
```

*Note: Needs to be tested to see if the above purges sub-folders (recursive)

Part 2:
Are you in charge of the server and *not* using it for (m)any other users?
Do you allow *system commands* in PHP?
If *yes*, it should be easy to run the command whenever http://mysite.com/additem is visited.

The above commands work from CLI, not tested yet the other way.